# Поиск по массиву JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
var input_text = "Москва";
var city = ["Рязань", "Москва" , "Новосибирск" , "Хабаровск"];
```

Как найти входную переменную в массиве городов и создать условие **true/false**?

Comment: с помощью jquery никак

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

Это делается без JQ.

[.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var input_text = "Москва";
var city = ["Рязань", "Москва" , "Новосибирск" , "Хабаровск"];

console.info(city.includes(input_text));
```